how change bass in C# bass.dll in runtime?
I am writing a player with the function of changing low frequencies in C# using the library bass.dll I have a problem with the low frequency change function. I use the BASS_FX_SET_PARAMETERS method, but there is no effect
private void FreaqBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        sound.ChangeBass((float)FreaqBar.Value);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Трек не выбран");
    }
}
public void ChangeBass(float gain)
{
    Bass.BASS_ChannelRemoveFX(Stream, (int)BASSFXType.BASS_FX_DX8_PARAMEQ);
    Bass.BASS_ChannelSetFX(Stream, BASSFXType.BASS_FX_DX8_PARAMEQ, 0);
    BASS_DX8_PARAMEQ bassboost = new BASS_DX8_PARAMEQ(100f, 18f, gain);
    Bass.BASS_FXSetParameters(Stream, bassboost);
}

I use the BASS_FX_SET_PARAMETERS method, but there is no effect

What is that bass.dll library? An answer to you question would need some information about that library. Is there any known API/documentation?

https://www.un4seen.com/
